# Converting date formats in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, nsdate

I have the date:

```
2011-08-31 14:12:24
```

and I want to convert it to the format

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
```

Is this the correct way of converting it?

```
NSString* time = [[[article valueForKey:@"published_at"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"T"] stringByAppendingString:@"Z"];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.Create an Instance of NSDateFormatter.

2.Set the "dateFormat" property of your NSDateFormatter instance to the initial date format.

3.Use the `dateFromString:` method and assign the value to an NSDate.

4.Set the "dateFormat" property of your NSDateFormatter instance to the desired date format.

5.Use the `stringFromDate:` method and pass the NSDate created in step 3 to the method; the returned string is the date you want.

Answer (score 0):

Well just adding the strings won't help you will have to do timezone conversion also.